# Can't read two lines at the same time using readlines() index out of range error

Tags: python, readlines

I have some text files contain 7 lines when I try to print line 3 and 4 using the following code, it prints line 3 then it gives me an index out of range error

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('Init.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fRead:
                line_3 = fRead.readlines()[3]
                line_4 = fRead.readlines()[4]
                print line_3
                print line_4
```

However when I run either one of the following codes I get no errors

**Code 1: Line 3 prints correctly**

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('Init.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fRead:
                line_3 = fRead.readlines()[3]
                print line_3
```

**Code 2: Line 4 prints correctly**

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('Init.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fRead:
                line_4 = fRead.readlines()[4]
                print line_4
```

**It seems as if I can't read both lines at the same time. This is so frustrating!**

Comment: Because you consumed the file object. It can only be iterated once. The first call to `readlines()` gives you a list, you only want data at a specific index after that, so why would you attempt to read the entire file twice to get values at single indices each time?

Comment: Awesome! thanks for explaining how the readlines() func works!

Comment: You're welcome. I came across a bit harsher than I intended, sorry. I only meant to make you question the logic and get to your own understanding :)

Comment: @roganjosh Someone read the new code of conduct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation:

> Help on built-in function readlines:
>
> readlines(hint=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
>       Return a list of lines from the stream.
>
> ```
> hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
> lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
> lines so far exceeds hint.
> ```

Once you have consumed all lines, the next call to `readlines` will be empty.

Change your function to store the result in a temporary variable:

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as fRead:
    lines = fRead.readlines()
    line_3 = lines[3]
    line_4 = lines[4]
    print line_3
    print line_4
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks for explaining how the readlines() func works!

Answer (score 1):

The method `readlines()` reads all lines in a file until it hits the EOF (end of file).
The "cursor" is then at the end of the file and a subsequent call to `readlines()` will not yield anything, because EOF is directly found.

Hence, after `line_3 = fRead.readlines()[3]` you have consumed the whole file but only stored the fourth (!) line of the file (if you start to count the lines at 1).

If you do

```
all_lines =  fRead.readlines()
line_3 = all_lines[3]
line_4 = all_lines[4]
```

you have read the file only once and saved every information you needed.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for explaining how the readlines() func works!